# Can someone please explain why this loop breaks early?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new to C programming and I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around pointers. I tried experimenting with a for loop to get a better understanding of how they work. I declared a variable outside the loop and tried using a pointer to the variable within the loop's condition to see how the variable would change as the loop executed.

I executed this first:

```
int main(void){
    int i = 5;
    for (int *m = &i;  *m < 10; *m++){
        printf("%d\n", *m);
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In this case the loop breaks early and my output is

```
5
5
```

but if i execute this

```
int main(void){
    int i = 5;
    for (int *m = &i;  *m < 10; i++){
        printf("%d\n", *m);
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get my expected output.

```
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

How are they different, and what causes the loop to break early in the first code snippet?

Comment: You need `(*m)++.` `++` has a higher priority than dereferencing `*`

Comment: In the first code snippet, the dereferenced pointer *m++ points to an unknown location which may cause unpredicted results. In your case it exited after 2 iterations. However, it may also cause an infinite loop.

Comment: If you use gcc or clang, compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and then run your program. The warning may look harmless: `warning: value computed is not used: *m++` but it's not. When running the program you'll get `AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow` and a pointer to where it happens.

Comment: The root problem is using a ++ operator together with other operators in the same expression, which is bad practice. Meaning that in a real program, the for loop should have been written with `int i` instead of a pointer in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Apologies if anything here is wrong. I am new to both C and this site so I may have made some mistakes, but this is what I have figured out from about an hour of playing around with it.

As others have commented, the problem is that you used *m++. If you wanted to do this in a similar way, you could do *m+=1. It seems like these are the same thing, but the problem essentially comes down to order of operations.

With *m++, the compiler is reading it as *(m++), so what is happening is you are increasing m (the address) and setting *m (the value pointed to), which is now pointing to a different number than before, to the previous address, what m was before it was incremented.

The reason that the loop only prints two fives is because the memory address is most likely going to be a very large integer, meaning that it is greater than 10 and breaking from the loop. If you were to run the program a few times, eventually you will have m be a negative number. In that case, you would get an output like:

```
5
-1663524456
5
```

I am not sure why it doesn't end up incrementing from that negative number up until it gets to 10, I am not sure. If someone else knows the answer to that, I would love to know, but in all my testing I never had it go through more than 2 loops.

Here is my code from testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int i = 5;
    int *m = &i;
    int n = 1;
    for (int *m = &i;  *m < 10; *m++){
        printf("in loop %d:\n*m = %d\n", n, *m);
        printf(" m = %d\n\n", m);
        n++;
        //printf("*m++ = %d\n\n", *m++);
    }
    printf("End of loop:\n*m = %d\n", *m);
    printf(" m = %d\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Example Result:

```
in loop 1:
*m = 5
 m = -65445932

in loop 2:
*m = -65445932
 m = -65445928

End of loop:
*m = 5
 m = -65445932
```

Here you can see that *m starts off pointing to i, and m is the starting address. Then after the first loop, m has moved to the next address (incremented by 4 as you would with an array), and *m has become the previous value of m. Then after the next loop, for some reason the m goes back to the starting address (this is the part that I am confused about and would like some help with) which is still pointing to the value of i. Again, I do not know why this breaks the loop, I believe this should go infinite because by this logic you would continue the loop, and then go to the same result as loop 2, but instead, the loop breaks when 5 < 10 is still true.